# Running krbticket method in gunicorn without ssh shell leads to Internal Server Error

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, kerberos

I got some problems when running my flask application with gunicorn as systemd service. Here is the code section:

```
from krbticket import KrbTicket

ticket = KrbTicket.init("admin", "admin.keytab") 
ticket.updater_start()
```

When I run gunicorn in SSH session like this:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 -k eventlet wsgi:app
```

everithing works ok. But if I run it as a systemd service like this:

```
[Unit]
After = network.target

[Service]
User = testuser
Group = www-data
WorkingDirectory = /srv/www/audit
Environment = "PATH=/srv/www/audit/auditenv/bin"
ExecStart = /srv/www/audit/auditenv/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 -k eventlet wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

I got an Iternal Server Error. Gunicorn log:

```
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/srv/www/audit/auditenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/srv/www/audit/auditenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/srv/www/audit/auditenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/srv/www/audit/audit_real.py", line 132, in title_search
    ticket = KrbTicket.init("admin", "admin.keytab")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/srv/www/audit/auditenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/krbticket/ticket.py", line 107, in init
    return KrbTicket.init_by_config(config)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/srv/www/audit/auditenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/krbticket/ticket.py", line 111, in init_by_config
    KrbCommand.kinit(config)
  File "/srv/www/audit/auditenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/krbticket/command.py", line 34, in kinit
    KrbCommand._call(config, commands)
  File "/srv/www/audit/auditenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/krbticket/command.py", line 93, in _call
    return retriable_call()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/srv/www/audit/auditenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/srv/www/audit/auditenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/retrying.py", line 205, in call
    if not self.should_reject(attempt):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/srv/www/audit/auditenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/retrying.py", line 189, in should_reject
    reject |= self._retry_on_exception(attempt.value[1])
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/srv/www/audit/auditenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/krbticket/command.py", line 78, in error_on_retry
    raise exception
  File "/srv/www/audit/auditenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/srv/www/audit/auditenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/krbticket/command.py", line 89, in retriable_call
    return subprocess.check_output(commands, universal_newlines=True, env=custom_env)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 466, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1901, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'kinit'
```

It looks like I'm missing something, but can't get the right solution.

Comment: The error is `No such file or directory: 'kinit'`. Where is the `kinit` binary installed? Maybe you need to explicitly set the `PATH` environment variable in your systemd unit.

Comment: @larsks kinit is installed in /usr/bin/kinit you were right. Everything is working fine after I add /usr/bin to PATH variable of the unit, thank you!